# How to update a value created with let in a recursive function

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a recursive function that keeps going until a certain number is reached. The function has two parameters. The first is a list of strings, while the second is a number that tells me how many iterations I'm supposed to do. I've tried using let in the beginning, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to increment the value I declare using let.

My function looks something like this.

```
    somefunction l n = let m = 0 in 
                       if (m < n) then somefunction (otherfunction l m) n
                       else l
```

This has the obvious problem that I don't increment the value of m anywhere so the function won't ever terminate. I'm still getting used to haskell so the syntax has been giving me some trouble. I feel like the solution to this should be pretty easy, but I can't seem to figure out how to go about it. I've thought of using a helper function that could increment the value of m and maybe call the otherfunction. This seems like the way to go, but I'm not sure on how to put it all together.

This is a homework assignment, so I would appreciate any kind of hint on how to solve this problem. I have all my other functions working, I just need to make them all work together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do indeed need a helper function that calls itself with an updated argument each time.

```
somefunction l n = loop 0
  where
    loop m
      | m < n = ...
      | otherwise = ...
```

Comment: So, the first guard will update the value of m if it's less than n. What about the second guard? I tried calling the function recursively, but it gave an error since it's expecting an int rather than a list of strings.

Comment: The second guard is where you say what the result should be when m is no longer less than n.  If you want to finish, then you would not use recursion there; just write an expression for the answer.  Of course, that means you have to know the answer!  Chances are, you want another argument to `loop` that keeps a running answer, in addition to the counter.  But without knowing what you're trying to compute, it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. The purpose of somefunction was to concatenate two lists of strings. Before the two lists are concatenated together, I would call another function to modify the list l in some way. The other function will simply use the same list twice to distribute the contents of each element with each other.  I would still like to figure how to do it with a helper function, so that I can see how to do it both ways.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution after thinking about it for a while. I was thinking of using a helper function to keep track of the current iteration, but that was proving to be a bit difficult. In the end, I realized that I could simply call the recursive function in the opposite order so that the function would use the n and go all the way down to 0, then it would call otherfunction. This way, the result was printed in the correct order and I didn't have to use a helper function.